# Helm doesn't take values YAMLs

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I’m working to install prometheus operator, I took the default helm chart and install it via the following command:

```
helm install po stable/prometheus-operator -n mon -f values.yaml
```

using [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) chart.

The installation was successful however it didn’t take the values from the `values.yaml` files, what am I doing wrong? e.g we don’t see two replicas of alert manger (minimal reproducible)

cat values.yaml

```
prometheus-operator:
  defaultRules:
  grafana:
    enabled: true
  alertmanager:
    alertmanagerSpec:
      replicas: 2
```

the values yaml is on the folder which I execute the command. I'm using Helm 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fairly certain it should look like this:

```
grafana:
  enabled: true
alertmanager:
  enabled: true
  alertmanagerSpec:
    replicas: 2
```

Comment: even if I use the prometheus operator chart ?

Comment: just look at the example values file: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/values.yaml#L73

Comment: I opend another similar question, please see if you can assist , thanks